# How can this excepction handling be made simpler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I have the equivalent to the following code:

```
class SomeError(Exception): pass

def do_things_with(fileobject):
    # Do things, and at some point the line below MAY be called
    raise SomeError

def try_another_approach():
    # Do different things, but at some point the line below MAY be called
    raise SomeError

try:
    try:
        with open('somefile') as somefile:
            do_things_with(somefile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        try_another_approach()
except SomeError:
    print('Ooops')
```

That is, I try to open a file (or any other thing that may raise certain other exceptions) and if that fails a different approach may be used, but BOTH approaches may raise the same set of exceptions.

Right now I have to handle this with a nested try/except, as shown, but I would love to do something like this:

```
try:
    with open('somefile') as somefile:
        do_things_with(somefile)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # I'd like to have any SomeError raised from the function below
    # at the except clause just below, to keep code compact as I may
    # be adding more exceptions in the future
    try_another_approach()
except SomeError:
    print('Ooops')
```

Of course that doesn't work (I get one of those `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred`), but it illustrates what I want to achieve: **handle exceptions raised both in the try block and in some except block with a later except block, without nesting**.

I don't **need** to avoid the nesting, I'm just curious about any way of solving this without having to nest, just in case.

Is it at all possible in Python?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Exceptions raised in an except clause will look for a handler in an outter block (i.e the nesting you do). There's no other way to go about this if in your current approach without nesting.

The only way you can remove the nesting is if you reduce the exceptions; that is, instead of `raise Error` you `return` a value as an indication that something went wrong. In that case you act on the returned value (with an `if` clause) instead of acting on the returned exception (with a `try-except` clause).

Comment: Thanks, @jim-fasarakis-hilliard, that's what I imagined but I was just curious. And the reason I was curious is because this pattern keeps appearing in code I have to maintain and not always can be replaced by a `return`. No big deal in using nesting, but sometimes, specially when you use `with` clauses, the indentation can be ugly deep.